# C# Copying Multiple Files Gives 'Could not find a part of the path' Error, Win Forms App

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to copy the contents of a folder into another folder using **OpenFileDialog**, but when I click ok it gives me  'Could not find a part of the path' even though I declared the destination path. This is my code

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewRow data = dataGridView1.Rows[index];
        selected = data.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {





        string strDestinationFolder = @"C:\Users\Ara\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\bin\Debug\pics\"+selected;
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (string fileName in ofd.FileNames)
            {
                File.Copy(fileName, strDestinationFolder + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            }
        }
```

the **Selected** variable gets it's value from a the selected row in a **datagridview** then I concatenate it with the destination folder(pics) path knowing that there is a directory that it's name corresponds with the **selected** variable in the (pics) folder, but when I hardcode the path like this

```
string strDestinationFolder = @"C:\Users\Ara\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\bin\Debug\pics\abc";
```

it works. How can I get the destination folder when I click **datagridview** row? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't `selected` empty?

Comment: At first it is empty, but when you click a row in the datagridview it gets a value.

Comment: Don't concat path yourself, it is a recipe for a disaster. Use `Path.Combine()` instead.
What's the value of `strDestinationFolder + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(fileName)`?

Comment: @RussKie The path is @"C:\Users\Ara\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\bin\Debug\pics\"+selected+"\+copied filename

Comment: What's the calculated path when you run the app?

Comment: @RussKie This @"C:\Users\Ara\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\bin\Debug\pics\"+selected+"\+copied filename

Comment: This is not "runtime calculated" path.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "pics" folder exists, but you never create a sub-folder named whatever `selected` is. So, when you try `...\pics\abc`, it works because it's putting `abc` in `pics` (which exists).

If `selected` is `test` and your filename is `abc`, then `strDestinationFolder + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));` is actually `...\pics\test\abc`. Since you never create the sub-folder with the name: `selected` (this example: `test`), it doesn't find it. So...

Try creating the sub-folder before the copy:

```
string strDestinationFolder = @"C:\Users\Ara\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp3\WindowsFormsApp3\bin\Debug\pics\"+selected;

// CREATE selected SUB-FOLDER
if(!Directory.Exists(strDestinationFolder))
    Directory.Create(strDestinationFolder);

// YOUR EXISTING CODE BELOW 
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.Multiselect = true;
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (string fileName in ofd.FileNames)
    {
        File.Copy(fileName, strDestinationFolder + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(fileName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still gives the same error. even when I manually create a subfolder that corresponds with the selected variable it still gives me the same error.